# How to print sequential number for records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with only one column (class) having records

```
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
```

I want to run a query so that the output will look like below.

```
Class | RowNumber
-----------------
a     |    1
a     |    2
a     |    3
a     |    4
b     |    1
b     |    2
b     |    3
b     |    4
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to how you have solved your problem with `ROW_NUMBER()`, you can also use the function like this:

```
SELECT
  Class,
  RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Class ORDER BY 1)
FROM tbldemo
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select class, count(*)
from <table>
group by class
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: it will give a | 4 b|4 but I need it should print second column individual value like above question. a |1 a|2 a| 3 like wise

Comment: @Marc_S: I need a output  a |1 a|2 a| 3 a |4 b|1 b|2 b|3 b|4. do you know how to achieve this

Comment: @all: Thanks for your reply, I got the answer  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY class) As SrNo, class  FROM  tbldemo
where class = 'a' union SELECT ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY class) As SrNo, class  FROM  tbldemo
where class = 'b'